# Typescript conditional extends based on parameters value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm quite new to Typescript and I'm trying to have a conditional extends based on a function argument value. The context is to define a widget for object selection that can be a select, a list of radio (a radio group) or a list of checkbox (a checkbox group). Each of this different widget accept different props, name: `SelectProps`, `RadioGroupProps` and `CheckboxGroupProps`. The widget selection is based on two parameters: `expand` (means we want a list of checkbox or radio) and `multiple` (means we want to select multiple elements or not).

```js
function SelectionWidget(props: SelectionWidgetProps) {}
```

Here, I want that:
if `props` matches `{expand: true, multiple: false}` then `SelectionWidgetProps` must extends `RadioGroupProps`.
if `props` matches `{expand: true, multiple: true}` then `SelectionWidgetProps` must extends `CheckboxGroupProps`.
otherwise, `SelectionWidgetProps` must extends `SelectProps`.

I tried the following:

```js
type SelectTypeExtend<T> = 
    T extends { expand: false } ? SelectProps : 
    T extends { expand: true; multiple: false } ? RadioGroupProps :
    T extends { expand: true; multiple: true; } ? CheckboxGroupProps :
    never;

interface SelectTypeProps extends SelectTypeExtends {
    multiple?: boolean;
    expand?: boolean;
}
```

But it doesn't work as `SelectTypeExtends` expects an argument.
Is it possible to achieve this with Typescript?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `interface` only with statically known types. It means that does not allow you to extend `SelectTypeProps` with `SelectTypeExtends` because `SelectTypeExtends` is a black box. Nobody know type of `T`.

In order to manage this case, you should use `type` instead of `interface`:

```js
type SelectProps = {
  tag: 'SelectProps'
}

type RadioGroupProps = {
  tag: 'RadioGroupProps'
}

type CheckboxGroupProps = {
  tag: 'CheckboxGroupProps '
}

type SelectTypeExtend<T> =
  T extends { expand: false } ? SelectProps :
  T extends { expand: true; multiple: false } ? RadioGroupProps :
  T extends { expand: true; multiple: true; } ? CheckboxGroupProps :
  never;

type SelectTypeProps<T> = { // <------ type instead of interface
  multiple?: boolean;
  expand?: boolean;
} & SelectTypeExtend<T>
```

---

Example with react components:

```js
import React from "react";

import {
  Select,
  SelectProps,
  Checkbox,
  CheckboxGroupProps,
  Radio,
  RadioGroupProps
} from "formik-antd";


export type SelectionComponentProps =
  | { expand?: false } & { options: SelectProps }
  | { expand: true; multiple?: false } & { options: RadioGroupProps }
  | { expand: true; multiple: true } & { options: CheckboxGroupProps };

function SelectionComponent(props: SelectionComponentProps) {
  if (props.expand) {
    if (props.multiple) {
      return <Checkbox.Group {...props.options} />;
    } else {
      return <Radio.Group {...props.options} />;
    }
  }
  return <Select {...props.options} />;
};

const select: SelectProps = 'unimplemented' as any;
const radio: RadioGroupProps = 'unimplemented' as any;
const checkbox: CheckboxGroupProps = 'unimplemented' as any;

export const TestRadio = () => {
  // Accept properties from RadioGroupProps but not from SelectProps or CheckboxGroupProps
  return [
    <SelectionComponent expand options={radio} />, // ok
    <SelectionComponent expand options={select} />, // expected error
    <SelectionComponent expand options={checkbox} />, // expected error
  ]
};

export const TestCheckbox = () => {
  // Accept properties from CheckboxProps but not from SelectProps or RadioGroupProps
  return [
    <SelectionComponent expand multiple options={checkbox} />, // ok
    <SelectionComponent expand multiple options={select} />, // expected error
    <SelectionComponent expand multiple options={radio} /> // expected error
  ]
};

export const TestSelect = () => {
  // Accept properties from SelectProps but not from RadioGroupProps or CheckboxGroupProps
  return [
    <SelectionComponent options={select} />, // ok
    <SelectionComponent options={radio} />, // expected error
    <SelectionComponent options={checkbox} />, // expected error
  ]
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9pejw)

I have slightly modified `SelectionComponentProps` type. Please keep in mind, that if you don't provide some property to react component, TS treats it as `undefined` and not as `false`, hence you need to make some of your `false` properties as a `partial`

Comment: Thank you very much. The last part I'm missing, is how to define my function signature with this?
```
const SelectType =  ({expand = false, multiple = false, ...props}: SelectTypeProps) => {}
```

Comment: @Vincent please provide more explanation. How do you want call this function and what this function should return. Do you want to pass `{multiple?: boolean; expand?: boolean;}` type as an argument to the function and return one of `*GroupProps`? Please share all three types `*GroupProps`

Comment: This function is a react functional component and return a React.Node. 
The types I want to extend are defined here:  
https://github.com/jannikbuschke/formik-antd/blob/master/src/checkbox/index.tsx. 
https://github.com/jannikbuschke/formik-antd/blob/master/src/radio/index.tsx. 
https://github.com/jannikbuschke/formik-antd/blob/master/src/select/index.tsx. 

```const SelectType = (props: SelectTypeProps) => {}```
I want to call it as a regular react component, like: 
```<SelectType multiple expand {...otherPropsCompatiblesWithCheckboxGroup} />```

Comment: @Vincent could you please still provide a minimum reproducible example? I think you can use a union `SelectProps | RadioGroupProps | CheckboxGroupProps` in this case instead of conditional types, but I'm not sure

Comment: Here is a codesandbox to better understand what I'm trying to achieve: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-dewdney-3gv08